# minima of a multivariate function

Tags: optimization

Say I have a function of 2 or more variables f(x,y,...). There is nothing given about the function (concave, convex etc). Is it always the case that minima you get by forcing some of these variables to zero always greater than what you get otherwise?

Comment: What do you mean by "forcing some of these variables to zero"? You mean, for example, given $f(x,y)$ then looking at $g(x)=f(x,0)$? Also, did you tried solving this?

Comment: yes exactly. I mean it is very intuitive to me, but is there a formal proof of this?

Comment: Hint, $\mbox{Range}(g)\subseteq\mbox{Range}(f)$

Comment: Formal proof: fixing some variables you get a subspace, and minimum over a subset is greater than that over the whole space.

Comment: Thanks @A.Γ., If you post it as answer, i will accept it.

Answer (score 1):

*You remember  me things we were doing, even with computers, about 60 years ago.*

Suppose a function of two variables $f(x,y)$ that you want to minimize **assuming** that the minimum is unique.

- So, fix $y=y_0$ and minimize $f(x,y_0)$ with respect to $x$; the best point corresponds to $x_0$.
- Now, minimize $f(x_0,y)$ with respect to $y$; the best point corresponds to $y_1$. Make $y_0=y_1$ and repeat step $1$.
- Repeat steps $1$ and $2$ until convergence.

You can generalize the procedure to any number of variables.

If I properly remember, in the very very first version of the IBM Scientific Subroutine Package, there was one subroutine performing like that

Comment: It is called [Coordinate descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinate_descent) or Cyclic Coordinates method. May stuck at a non-stationary point.

Comment: @A.Γ. I even did not know that there was a name for it and that we could find documentation about it. Thanks for the link. For sure, there can be many problems with such a primitive method. Cheers.